# Two menus from the same side

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm looking for an example of something I want to do or to hint how to do it.
I want to create menu from one side of Viewport of Sencha Touch 2 and after this 
to replace this menu with other menu. When I call

```
 Ext.Viewport.setMenu(menu, {
     side: 'left'
 });
```

It working OK but after I call setMenu with other menu the new attached menu replaces old menu and that is the idea. But the problem appears when I want to return other menu. Is there is a way to keep instance of old menu somewhere? I just do not want to recreate the previous menu again. I tried to replace second menu with Container but it is no so flexible like menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce you problem. I wrote a Fiddle and create 3 menu's. I show and hide them without any problem. I can even select a menu using `Ext.Viewport.down()`.

Code from the [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/u2q/preview):

```
var menu1 = Ext.create('Ext.Menu', {
    itemId: 'menu1',
    items: [{
        text: 'MenuItem 1',
        iconCls: 'settings'
    }]
});

var menu2 = Ext.create('Ext.Menu', {
    itemId: 'menu2',
    items: [{
        text: 'MenuItem 2',
        iconCls: 'compose'
    }]
});

var menu3 = Ext.create('Ext.Menu', {
    itemId: 'menu3',
    items: [{
        text: 'MenuItem 3',
        iconCls: 'star'
    }]
});



Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        var me = this,
            menuus = new Array(menu1, menu2, menu3);

        me.showMenu(menu1);

        Ext.defer(function() {
            me.showMenu(menu2);
        }, 1000);

        Ext.defer(function() {
            me.showMenu(menu3);
        }, 2000);

        Ext.defer(function() {
            me.showMenu(menu1);
        }, 3000);

        Ext.defer(function() {
            var menuFromViewport = Ext.Viewport.down('#menu2');
            me.showMenu(menuFromViewport);
        }, 4000);
    },

    showMenu: function(menu) {        
        Ext.Viewport.hideMenu('left');

        Ext.Viewport.setMenu(menu, {
            side: 'left'
        });

        Ext.Viewport.showMenu('left');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I come to solution how to do this. This is example of my solution:

```
    Ext.application({
    name : 'Test',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'container',
            fullscreen: true,
            html: 'Application panel',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Show first menu',
                listeners: {
                    tap: function() {
                        Ext.Viewport.removeMenu('left');
                        var menu = Ext.create('Ext.Menu', {
                            items: [
                                {
                                    text: 'Settings on first menu',
                                    iconCls: 'settings'
                                },
                                {
                                    text: 'New Item on first menu',
                                    iconCls: 'compose'
                                },
                                {
                                    text: 'Star on first menu',
                                    iconCls: 'star'
                                }
                            ]
                        });
                        Ext.Viewport.setMenu(menu, {
                            side: 'left',
                            reveal: true
                        });
                        Ext.Viewport.showMenu('left');
                    }
                }
            },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Show second menu',
                    listeners: {
                        tap: function() {
                            Ext.Viewport.removeMenu('left');

                            var secondmenu = Ext.create('Ext.Menu', {
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        text: 'Settings on second menu',
                                        iconCls: 'settings'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text: 'New Item on second menu',
                                        iconCls: 'compose'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text: 'Star on second menu',
                                        iconCls: 'star'
                                    }
                                ]
                            });
                            Ext.Viewport.setMenu(secondmenu, {
                                side: 'left',
                                reveal: true
                            });
                            Ext.Viewport.showMenu('left');
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```